# Service will not start on one computer - logon failure

Tags: windows-8, login, services, domain

Cannot start windows service, error logon failure.

But

- account is on the domain and in local admin group and has service logon policy set.
- the password has been reset and account is not locked out.
- the service works on another machine on the same domain that I do not have access to.
- setting account details by the command line with sc works fine, but can not start service.
- even rebooted the machine.

why

I was tasked with creating a custom service that was installed on a server in our old domain and ran with a dedicated account. It worked perfectly and everyone was happy.

A couple of weeks a go we all moved to a new domain and the older server was decommissioned. The new server had the older service installed along with a new domain user to execute the service. The code I wrote failed because the server had new components on it. This was logged in the services custom event log, very clear, missing dll.

Rebuilt the service with newer components and tried to get the owner to deploy it, they refused until I had it working locally with the new domain service runner user account.

Using my personal domain account on my machine to execute the service runs fine. Any attempt to start it with the domain account gives logon failure.

I was able to run

```
sc qc SERVICENAME
sc query SERVICENAME
sc queryex SERVICENAME
```

on both my machine and the server that works and they are identical.

I used

```
sc config SERVICENAME obj= NEWDOMAIN\ACCOUNTNAME password= PASSWORD
```

to ensure that there was absolutely no way I was entering the password incorrectly. Additionally I got the domain admins to reset the password and ensure the account is not locked out.

Why on this one machine can I not run this service as this domain user?

- Service works with other user on this machine.
- Service(old version) executes on target server with same domain user.

Comment: Is there a need to load the service under the user account? Try to run the service as a network or system.

Comment: the domain account has the permissions needed for the service to do its job.

Comment: What does the service and what resources it needs in the domain? For example, you can give the right to a particular machine in the domain of the resource, and then there is no need to set up a user account for the service.

Comment: Possible service checks appliances user to the group and will not start. What a mistake provides service in the event log when the launch occurs?

Comment: The service uses the Team Foundation Server API. The TFS server is locked down via domain users. So the service has to be run as the correct user to authenticate at the API level.